# How to compare variables as String?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

If the `myData.value` is `blablabla` then variable `tmp` should be equal `ABC`:

```
 <div th:with="tmp=*{myData.value} eq 'blablabla' ? 'ABC' : 'XYZ'">
      <br>
      <span th:utext="*{myData.value}">___</span>
      <br>
      <span th:utext="${tmp}">___</span>
</div>
```

**Output**:

> blablabla
>   XYZ

Comment: have you tried moving the closing curly bracket to the end of the statement? Looks like only {myData.value} is recognized by thymeleaf as a statement

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of thymeleaf utilities such as `strings` with that fashion

```
<p th:text="${#strings.equals(first, second)}"></p>
<p th:text="${#strings.equalsIgnoreCase(first, second)}"></p>
```

in your case it would be :

```
${#strings.equals(myData.value, blablabla)}
```

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#strings.equals(myData.vaue, blablabla)"

Comment: maybe it is because of myData.vaue which does exist

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer. It helps others :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for string comparison it's `==` in thymeleaf

```
"tmp=*${myData.value ==  'blablabla' ? 'ABC' : 'XYZ'}"
```

Comment: `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "tmp=*${myData.value == 'blablabla' ? 'ABC' : 'XYZ'}"`