# Parameter to String in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

When the parameter `*{mydata.value}` is enum then how to transform it into String in thymeleaf?

I want to compare

`if:*{mydata.value == "aaa"}`

It gives error. 
I think it is because I should do something like:

`if:*{mydata.value.toString() == "aaa"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
if:*{mydata.value.toString().equals("aaa")}
```

I'm not very familiar with thymeleaf, however that is a common issue in Java. Using '==' will compare the reference to the object, but the .equals() will compare the contents of the string.

If 'mydata.value' is already a string, you can remove the '.toString()'.

If it isn't a string already, you can also use:

```
if:*{String.valueOf(mydata.value).equals("aaa")}
```

[See more examples of why this happens here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906019/how-to-compare-variables-as-string/57906323?noredirect=1#comment102235058_57906323 @Danyal Sandeelo said `for string comparison it's == in thymeleaf` ... so I'm confused now.

Comment: @wykopowiedz I'm not really sure honestly. Is your code still not working, even after trying .equals()?

Comment: Will try tommorrow, cuz left my computer ;) and I will give you an info